# Running SequentialFeatureSelector with tree base model seems to be wrong

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection, boosting

I'm little bit confused about the integration of using feature selection (`SequentialFeatureSelector` with `k_features="best"`) with `RandomForest` or `XGboost` models

- When using tree base algorithms like `random-forest` or `xgboost` the models are making their own feature selection algorithm (they don't use the whole set of features).
- When using feature selection approach with wrapper method, the running model use the X features at each step and run algorithm to tests its score (the score of the algorithm when using X features).
- But if we are using `SequentialFeatureSelector` with `RandomForest` or `XGboost` models, the `SFS` algorithm runs the model on each step with X features (but behind the scene the model gives the score with less (maybe random set of features)).
- For example: We can get 10 best features with `SFS & XGboost`, but after doing some `hyper-parameters` for `xgboost` with the dataset of the selected 10 features, we can get winning tree with 6 features.

So is it right using feature selection approach with wrapper method of random forest or xgboost ?

Answer (score 1):

Random Forest and XGBoost don't select features. They inherently subsample the features at each tree/boosting iteration, which is part of their procedure to fight with overfitting. So, XGBoost doesn't produce a winning three with, say, 6 features.

The feature selector algorithm can use any estimator, and it selects the features greedily (either forward or backward) based on the scoring function.